# What does "as has" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"In Britain the price of a new drug for cystic fibrosis has provoked fury, as has the government’s refusal to pay it." What does "as has" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence can be broken into two sentences, ""In Britain the price of a new drug for cystic fibrosis has provoked fury" and "The government's refusal to pay it[the price] has also provoked fury". "As has" helps join the two sentences by having "has" refer to "provoked" and create one concise sentence.